# Inter-process communication with XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, ipc

I have two applications: X and Y.
X has a set of variables (stored in an object of a class), which have to be transferred to Y. I am planning to use an XML-file as a record stored on disk that can be accessed by name by both applications. X writes the data to that XML-file and Y reads it.

I thought I can use XmlSerializer (System.Xml.Serialization) to accomplish this. With XmlSerializer I can create an XML file that looks like this:

```
<MonsterCollection>
  <Monsters>
    <Monster name="a">
     <Health>5</Health>
    </Monster>
    <Monster name="b">
     <Health>3</Health>
    </Monster>
  </Monsters>
</MonsterCollection>
```

When Y reads this XML file, it does not know the actual data type of variables *Health*. Therefore, the original class has to be defined in both X and Y. Is there a way to store the datatypes in the XML-file, as well? In the end, I would like to accomplish something like this:

```
<Monster name="a" type="" help="This is a monster">
  <var name="Health" type="uint16" val="5" help="Healthiness of this monster" /> 
</Monster>
<Monster name="b" type="" help="This is a monster">
  <var name="Health" type="uint16" val="3" help="Healthiness of this monster" /> 
</Monster>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877202/how-to-show-data-types-in-xml-serialization

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below mentioned code

```
 public class Monster 
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("val")]
    public int val { get; set; }
}
```

for ref [serialize-object-to-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503762/serialize-object-to-element-with-attributes-and-children)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I'm wondering, if there is a way to avoid declaring class "Monster" in both applications X and Y. Even when I use XmlAttribute to store the data as attributes (instead of elements), I still have to declare class "Monster" in application Y, as well. Is that correct?

Comment: if you are using dll of first application into your second application then you don't need to create that class again

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I just have to use dll's :-). That way, I do not even have to use XmlAttribute anymore. Or do you know how I could use the datatype stored as XmlAttribute, when I deserialize the XML-file in application Y?

Comment: you can use the typeof key

Comment: you can take the value in var and that cast it with value you received from xml.